# Open an url in Chrome without using the cache via command line

Tags: google-chrome, command-line, browser-cache

I use the command `chrome --new-window htp://www.example.com/` to open a url, but the page is opened using the last saved in the cache.

Is there a way to open a URL from the command line forcing the loading ignoring the cache?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try the following command:

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --new-window --aggressive-cache-discard --disable-notifications --disable-remote-fonts --disable-reading-from-canvas --disable-remote-playback-api --disable-shared-workers --disable-voice-input --enable-aggressive-domstorage-flushing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544664/open-an-url-in-chrome-without-using-the-cache-via-command-line#12545236 %U &
```

That works for me in **Chrome Version 54.0.2840.100 (64-bit) on Linux Mint Qiana**

But it won't log me out of any sites unless I quit the browser first.

Answer (score 5):

Adding the switch `--disable-application-cache` should work. Starting it incognito (`--incognito`) might also work. See also [here](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) for more command line switches.

Comment: I looked in list of commands and have not found other thing that I seek. Is there a command to open a new window on top? Currently it opens hidden behind the active window.

Comment: I think you can better use an autohotkey script, that will give you far more possibilities.

Comment: I know autohotkey but I can not imagine how to use it in this issue. You can make a suggestion, please?

Comment: In autohotkey you can make a window topmost. Regarding the cache; maybe you can specify a different (empty) cache location on the commandline, or first delete all files in the cache before starting chrome.

Comment: `--incognito` worked in my case. Any other alternatives here at this point didn't. I open the same web page URL just re-running the IIS Express server over different folders. Incognito gets the new version every time I open chrome from command line. An alternative I didn't want  was [cache-buster](https://www.keycdn.com/support/what-is-cache-busting/) to the URL. `--disable-application-cache` is no longer listed on [peter site](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/).

Comment: `--incognito` only worked because I closed all other incognito windows on that chrome profile before reopening it. If I keep one old incognito window open and then run the command line again, it loads the cached version.