# How do you save and preview an HTML file from temp folder?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, temp

I'm developing an HTML editor in C# where you can edit your code in the [FastColoredTextBox.dll](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/161871/Fast-Colored-TextBox-for-syntax-highlighting) component. You will have this option in the MenuStrip called "Preview in browser" and there will be a drop down item called "Chrome" and "Iexplore" etc. I want it instead of saving the file, i want it to make a file in the Temp folder and preview it. and after we've modified the code again, the file will update as we preview it again. This is what i have so far:

```
string location = null;
string sourcecode = FastColoredTextBox1.Text;
location = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + "\\TempSite.html";

using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(location, true))
{
    writer.Write(sourcecode);
    writer.Dispose();
}
try
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("chrome.exe", location);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Interaction.MsgBox(ex.Message);
}
```

How do you achieve this?

Comment: Q: What happens when you try this code?  Does TempSite.html get written?  Can you view it manually in a browser?  Can you start Chome (or IE or FF programmatically)?  If not, what happens when you try?

Comment: It saved and worked, but it does not update itself. So when i previewed it for the second time, it will show the previous one.

Comment: Fixed code block

Comment: Cache issue perhaps? If you F5 after chrome opens is the correct content displayed? (writer.Dispose(); is redundant btw)

Comment: In that case launch chrome with the cache:  [Open an url in Chrome without using the cache via command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544664/open-an-url-in-chrome-without-using-the-cache-via-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

Q: How do you save and preview an HTML file from temp folder?

A: You're already doing precisely that :)

Q: Why does my browser keep re-displaying the original image?

A: Because your browser is reading the html from cache.

SOLUTION:

Give your new file a different name.  For example:

```
location = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + Path.GetTempFileName() + ".html";
```

... OR ...

```
location = Path.GetTempPath() + Guid.NewGuid().ToString()  + ".html";
```

You can also simply hit `<F5>` to refresh, `<Ctl-Shift-Del>` to clear cache, or disable cache in your browser.

Comment: Thanks ill try that.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Just i have one problem: It will save the file in the Temp folder. But after previewing it, why doesn't it delete itself? Please help.